# Split a slice of bytes after a given separator/delimiter

Tags: c#, split

How can you split a slice of bytes after a given separator/delimiter in C#?

Let say you have this byte array: `byte[] array = {1, 0x2C, 2, 0x2C, 3, 4, 5};`

and your delimiter is **0x2C**

The wanted result should be: **array =  {1, 2, 3}**

Can someone please show how that is done correct?

i want to: split a byte array into sub-bytes based on specified delimiting byte

Comment: What does "split" mean in this context? Do you want two arrays? Just the first half? Do you want a new array, or to wipe the remaining part of the existing array? Most important: what code do you have so far?

Comment: so we have `{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}` if we split by `2` (while preserving delimiter) we'll have `{1}, {2}, {2}, {2} {3, 4, 5}`. How can we get `{1, 2, 3}` from this? Please note, that `0x2 == 2`, that's why we have in fact `{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: Hi there ! sorry i was not clear. I want to split a byte array into sub-bytes based on specified delimiting byte i hope it give seense

Comment: sorry it should be 0x2C not 0x2

Comment: @hanerikjansen What about the values `4` and `5` in your example?

Comment: @Progman the end result should be: array = {1, 2, 3}; after 3 there is no delimiter (0x2C)

Comment: Uh, then what would be the result for `{1, 0x2C, 2, 3, 4, 0x2C, 5, 6}`, for example?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace that would be  {1, 2, 5}; for {1, 0x2C, 2, 3, 4, 0x2C, 5, 6}

Comment: How so? Can you precisely explain the logic behind getting {1, 2, 4} from `{1, 0x2C, 2, 3, 4, 0x2C, 5, 6}`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo meant: {1, 2, 5}; not {1, 2, 4};

Comment: So, if i understand this correctly, then you actually do not really want to split or slice a byte array. It seems you want to get the first byte in the array and each byte that follows some specific "marker" byte. Is this correct?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Sorry my English is not good..You are correct.

Comment: Oops, yes. I forgot about the 1st byte. I would suggest you eithere replace the question text or write an entirely new question that more precisely describes the desired logic. Avoid talking about splitting or slicing, as this does not properly convey what you want to achieve. Oh, and also cover edge cases your program potentially has to deal with. I am thinking of something like `{0x2C, 2, 0x2C, 3, 4, 5}` (the 1st byte being a marker), `{1, 0x2C, 2, 0x2C}` (the last byte being a marker), `{1, 0x2C, 2, 0x2C, 0x2C, 0x2C, 3, 4, 5}` (two, three or more subsequent marker bytes), etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see (reverse engineering) you want:

- having an array, say `{1, 0x2C, 2, 0x2C, 3, 4, 5}` and delimiter `0x2C`
- you want to split the array by delimiter and return first items of each group when available:

```
{1, 0x2C, 2, 0x2C, 3, 4, 5}
      ^        ^
      Split by these

Groups are
  {1}
  {2}
  {3, 4, 5}

First items of each group are
  {1, 2, 3}
```

If its your case ([fiddle yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGAJkK))

```
using System.Linq;

...

byte[] array = {1, 0x2C, 2, 0x2C, 3, 4, 5};

byte delimiter = 0x2C;

List<byte> list = new();

if (array.Length > 0 && array[0] != delimiter)
  list.Add(array[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; ++i) 
  if (array[i] == delimiter && array[i + 1] != delimiter)
    list.Add(array[i + 1]);

byte[] result = list.ToArray();
```